# Replacing popup text depending on button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here is code that creates a button that calls a popup:

```
<a href="#positionWindow" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="flow">popup button</a>
```

This is the code that creates the popup with jQuery Mobile:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="positionWindow" class="ui-content popup" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
      <p> Replace the text here depending on which button is pressed </p>
</div>
```

How do I create multiple buttons that all call the same code used to create the popup and then replace the text inside of the popup depending on the button pressed?

Comment: So how is the button created? Not really clear what you are asking

Comment: The popup gets created inside of that div. It's using jQuery Mobile to create it.

Comment: But your question was about multiple buttons using same code to create each button. Confusing

Comment: Sorry. I made an edit so hopefully it makes more sense. I want to be able to replace the text in the p tag of the div with id "positionWindow" with text from the p tag of the div with id "text1", assuming that the user presses popup button 1...

Comment: Edit the question to explain exactly what you are trying to do..not just in comments. It still says *" one instance of the code used to create the button."* and I have no idea what that means

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. Make any more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me fine to use just one popup and dynamically set the content. Instead of use the `href` in markup, You should open your popup from code:

```js
$(document).on("vclick", "a[data-popup]", function(e) {
  var cases = [
      "You pressed Button 1",
      "You pressed Button 2"
    ],
    id = $(this).data("popup");
  $("#msg-block").text(cases[id - 1]);
  $("#myPopup").popup("option", "transition", "flow").popup("open");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>Header</h2></div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a class="ui-btn" data-popup="1" href="#">Popup Button 1</a>
      <a class="ui-btn" data-popup="2" href="#">Popup Button 2</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content popup" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
      <p id="msg-block"> Replace the text here depending on which button is pressed </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Explanation: to bind the button to the text message, i am using in my example a custom `data-attribute` but - if you prefer - you could use just the `id` of the buttons. Up to you.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem I am having now is being able to format the text inside the popup. I can't use html text formatting.

Comment: Why not? Instead of `$("#msg-block").text(cases[id - 1]);` just use `$("#msg-block").html(cases[id - 1]);` and put your markup inside the cases array, that's it!